How Can I Make API Responses Type-Safe Based on Requested Fields in JavaScript?
I work on the frontend team, and the server team has started using a different approach for API requests. They now require me to send a property with the specific fields I want to be returned in the response.
For example:
http.post(`/api/v1/users`, { requiredFields: [1, 2, 3] }) 
// The response will be [{ firstname, lastname, age }]
// This means that firstname is 1, lastname is 2, and so on.

I want to make the response type-safe based on the numbers I send.
Here's a small function that simulates what I need to send and what I get:
function server(fields) {
  const allFields = {
    1: 'firstname',
    2: 'lastname',
    3: 'age',
    4: 'address',
    5: 'email'
  };

  const result = {};

  fields.forEach(field => {
    if (allFields[field]) {
      result[allFields[field]] = null;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

I thought of creating an interface, type, enum, or some schema, but I'm not sure how to integrate that into JavaScript.

As a side note, it seems odd that they've decided to use numbers to represent the required fields instead of using the actual property names.

You can take a look at this demo:
interface UserResponse {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    email: string;
};

const allFields = {
    1: 'firstname' as const,
    2: 'lastname' as const,
    3: 'age' as const,
    4: 'address' as const,
    5: 'email' as const
};

type AllFields = typeof allFields;
type AllFieldsKeys = keyof AllFields;
type ToProp<T extends number> = T extends AllFieldsKeys ? AllFields[T]: never;

type FullResult = {
    [p in AllFieldsKeys as ToProp<p>] : UserResponse[ToProp<p>]
}

function server<T extends AllFieldsKeys>(fields: T[]): Pick<FullResult, ToProp<T>> {
  return fields.reduce((prev: any, curr) => {
    // In real life value will probably not be null
    return (prev as any)[curr] = null; 
  }, {});
}

const test = server([1,3,4]);
console.log(test.address); // OK string
console.log(test.firstname); // OK string
console.log(test.lastname); // ERROR
console.log(test.age); // OK number
console.log(test.email); // ERROR

Note
As others have mentioned, using numbers instead of property names is probably not a good idea. If you use the property names, the code will be easier to understand:
interface AllFields {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    email: string;
};

type AllFieldsKeys = keyof AllFields;

type ToProp<T extends keyof AllFields> =
    T extends AllFieldsKeys ?
        AllFields[T]: never;

function server<T extends AllFieldsKeys>(fields: T[]): Pick<AllFields, T> {
  return fields.reduce((prev: any, curr) => {
     // Backend will probably return something not null
    return (prev as any)[curr] = null;
  }, {});
}

const test = server(["address","age"]);
console.log(test.address); // OK  string
console.log(test.firstname); // ERROR
console.log(test.lastname); // ERROR
console.log(test.age); // OK number
console.log(test.email); // ERROR


The server is request a numbers, but could I build a request interface that typescript will infer it to response object and in js it send the numbers fields?

The first solution in my answer uses numbers; the second uses strings. The second is easier to understand and maintain, which is why I recommend it. If you cannot change the way the BE works, choose solution 1.

I don't have control over the server. I just send the numbers for the fields I want to retrieve, and they handle it on their end. They use some form of RPC, but it's not gRPC.
